# Azure deployment failed with error SubscriptionNotRegistered

Tags: azure

I just signed up for a new Azure account, hoping to get setup to use the text translation API. I tried to set this up by finding the text translation resource, and add it. However, when I hit the "create" button, it fails.

When I go to the error logs, I see an error `"The subscription 'c8b161f4-26be-4d3b-b924-0fe9b4072339' is not registered."`, with an error code `SubscriptionNotRegistered`. I cannot seem to find any information about this error on Google.

Has anyone encountered this error before, or know how to debug it further?

**Update**

Under **More Services** > **Subscriptions** > **Free Trial** > **Resource providers**, I see `Microsoft.CognitiveServices` permanently listed as "Registering". If I click the option to "Unregister", it seems to become permanently stuck in the "Unregistering" state, and registering again gets stuck again.. If I click "Re-Register", nothing happens. If I look in the activity log, it acts like the unregister/register events are going through successfully.

Configuration:

[image: configuration]

Deployment error:

[image: deployment error]

Operation details:

[image: operation details]

Resource providers:

[image: resource providers]

Activity log after unregistering/registering:

[image: activity log]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "Resource Provider" section of your Subcription. Make sure you have "Microsoft.CognitiveServices" provider registered.

Comment: Thanks so much, that feels like it's pointing in the right direction. I updated the description with what I found in the "Resource Provider" section. It looks like it's stuck in the "registering" state. Any more ideas on how to resolve that?

Comment: Not sure why, but after unregistering and reregistering, then waiting about an hour, it now seems to be working. Thanks for your help in figuring out the issue.

Comment: You are welcome, funny enough had a similar issue like 20 minutes before you posted your question :)